# hidden_field working with two models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, forms

Rather new still to RoR... I'm massively confused now how to accomplish the following:

I have following under my app/views/packjobs/_form.html.erb

```
<td><%= f.collection_select(:pj_packer, @packers, :p_name, :p_name, { :include_blank => true} ) %></td>
<%= f.hidden_field :packer_id, :value => @packers.id  %>
<td><%= f.text_field :pj_guestpacker %></td>
```

I have two models packers and packjobs.

```
class Packjob < ActiveRecord::Base  
   belongs_to :packer
end

class Packer < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :packjobs
end
```

I ordered the packers list in the controller for the dropdown and thought maybe that's what is causing the issue.

```
# GET /packjobs/new.xml
  def new
    @packjob = Packjob.new
    @datestamp = Time.now.strftime("%m/%d/%Y %I:%M:%S %P")
    @packers = Packer.find(:all, :conditions => { :p_team => "t" }, :order => "p_name")
    @rigs = Rig.find(:all, :conditions => { :rig_status => "t" }, :order => "rig_type_number")

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # new.html.erb
      format.xml  { render :xml => @packjob }
    end
  end
```

The schema for packjobs is the following:

```
-- Describe PACKJOBS
CREATE TABLE "packjobs" (
    "id" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL,
    "pj_packer" VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    "pj_guestpacker" VARCHAR(255),
    "pj_rig_type_number" VARCHAR(255),
    "pj_damage" VARCHAR(255),
    "pj_extranotes" VARCHAR(255),
    "created_at" DATETIME,
    "updated_at" DATETIME
, "packer_id" integer)
```

I'm able to populate the dropdown with Packer names for :pj_packer; but I'd like to pass the Packer ID to :packer_id.

I keep getting: `NoMethodError in Packjobs#new  undefined method 'id' for #<Array:0xa32828c>`

**EDIT:**

Ideally I'd like a hidden field to capture the ID of the selected packer.

Comment: The error is sensible. @packers is an array, which does not have 'id' method.

Comment: How do I parse the ID from the @packers array?

Comment: There isn't a single `id` because it is a list of `Packers`.

Comment: Do you intend packer_id to be the id of the packer selected for pj_packer?

Comment: Correct.  Is is possible my troubles stem from the fact that scaffold used XML instead of JSON?

Comment: @Levi Stanley: that's exactly what I'm after...with a hidden field.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The data model is the rootof the issue. `pj_packer` and `packer_id` are capturing the same information in different fields. You want to remove the `pj_packer` field and just use the relationship (`packer_id`).

Then your view becomes the following:

```
<td><%= f.collection_select(:packer_id, @packers, :p_name, :p_id, { :include_blank => true} ) %></td>
<td><%= f.text_field :pj_guestpacker %></td>
```

Then when you need the old `pj_packer` value, you can call `@packjob.packer.p_name` instead of `@packjob.pj_packer` to get the same value without having the extra field.

If you still need to keep the `pj_packer` field for other reasons, you can set it in a before save callback:

```
class Packjob < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :packer

  before_save :set_pj_packer

  def set_pj_packer
    self.pj_packer = packer.try(:p_name)
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

The following will work for sure.

`<%= f.select :packer_id, :options_for_select(@packers.map{|p| [p.p_name,p.id]}),
{:include_blank => true}%>`

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
<td><%= f.select :packer_id, options_from_collection_for_select(@packers, :id, :p_name, @packjob.packer_id), :include_blank => true %></td>
<td><%= f.text_field :pj_guestpacker %></td>
```