# Assign two columns with one collection_select

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to assign a user_id to one column and user_name to another column on each post using 1 collection_select.

Is that possible?  Or is this a mass assignment issue?

Comment: Hmm that's kind of weird to do that. Why do you want to do this way? Because you can still use this to get the user_name of the post's user: `@post.user.name`.

Comment: Mainly in case I need to export the db...I want the user's name and id to be present.

Comment: You could set a before_save statement which would retrieve the user's name and set it to the Post itself?

Comment: Absolutely!  That's works!!! Thanks.

Comment: Great, post an answer to your own question is case somebody needs to do the same as you ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved with this help from [MrYoshiji](https://stackoverflow.com/users/976775/mryoshiji) and [Levi Stanley](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1454117/levi-stanley) whom replied with the answer to this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13735164/hidden-field-working-with-two-models):

```
   before_save :set_user_name

   def set_user_name
      self.user_name = usepacker.try(:p_name)
   end
```